# How to find which rule take long time to finish

Tags: drools, rule-engine

We have around 15,000 rules running and it takes 2 hours to complete. I would like to figure out which rule takes long time. Its not possible for me to go to each rule and log it. So I implemented the AgendaEventListener and override afterMatchFired() method. I know which rules fired. But how do I know which rule took long time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the time to execute the match, update your listener to implement the `beforeMatchFired` method as well. When the `beforeMatchFired` method triggers, start the timer. When the same rule's `afterMatchFired`  triggers, stop the timer and log it. You'll want to also track match cancelled to discard unnecessary timers.

Remember to track this on a per-rule basis -- you'll need to identify each rule uniquely (package + name should be specific enough). Note that this exercise will get a little complicated if you have rules that extend other rules.

Comment: Just a comment here, because the term "rules execution" is sometimes used for both "rules evaluation" and "activation executions". The method described by @Roddy can be used to calculate the "activation executions" time. If you are wondering why your rules take a long time to be evaluated, then things get extremely complicated (if not impossible) because it is not that Drools evaluates each condition of each rule independently or even sequentially.

Comment: Agreed. If the java objects involved are particularly complex, I would suggest attempting to instrument those instead. Another thing that could also be happening is that there may be 'update' (or similar) calls which are causing the rules to be re-evaluated as a whole more times than needed (or expected).

Comment: @EstebanAliverti we now trace the number of constraint evaluation, see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67104829/4206

Comment: Great! I didn't know about that.

Answer (score 0):

Rather that doing your own profile, you should take a look at the new `drools-metric` module that solves exactly your problem.

From the [manual](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.52.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#performance-tuning-drl-ref_drl-rules)

> Use the drools-metric module to identify the obstruction in your rules
> You can use the drools-metric module to identify slow rules especially
> when you process many rules. The drools-metric module can also assist
> in analyzing the Drools engine performance. Note that the
> drools-metric module is not for production environment use. However,
> you can perform the analysis in your test environment.
>
> To analyze the Drools engine performance using drools-metric, add
> drools-metric to your project dependencies and enable trace logging
> for org.drools.metric.util.MetricLogUtils , as shown in the following
> example:

Answer (score 0):

Try `RulesChronoAgendaEventListener` and `RulesChronoChartRecorder` from [da-utils](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.droolsassert/da-utils)

Both gives you real-time JMX monitoring, showing average and max execution time for each rule. Second gather jfreechart data to show you values in time, which gives you perfect sense of overall performance and 'problematic' cases.

Register session listener

```
AgendaEventListener rulesChrono = new RulesChronoChartRecorder().withMaxThreshold(500).schedule();
session.addEventListener(rulesChrono);
```

Print per rule statistic

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
rulesChrono.getPerfStat().values()
        .forEach(s -> sb.append(format("%n%s - min: %.2f avg: %.2f max: %.2f activations: %d", s.getDomain(), s.getMinTimeMs(), s.getAvgTimeMs(), s.getMaxTimeMs(), s.getLeapsCount())));
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Draw charts

```
Map<String, TimeSeries> rulesMaxChart = rulesChrono.getRulesMaxChart();
Map<String, TimeSeries> rulesMinChart = rulesChrono.getRulesMinChart();
rulesChrono.getRulesAvgChart().entrySet()
        .forEach(e -> ChartUtils.pngChart(format("charts/%s.png", e.getKey()), 1024, 500, e.getValue(), Color.black, rulesMaxChart.get(e.getKey()), Color.lightGray, rulesMinChart.get(e.getKey()), Color.lightGray));
```

For the second you'll need [jfreechart dependency](https://search.maven.org/artifact/jfree/jfreechart)